# Why does my UIPickerView in my storyboard on a view controller, display as all white colour?

Tags: ios, colors

I have added a PickerView to a ViewController in my iPhone storyboard, however it doesn't display in the correct default colours, it displays as all white, except the text colour which is black. I'm using the latest version of Xcode and building for iOS v7.

Answer (score 0):

iOS 7 has changed the UI of the components like `UIPickerView`. This is the new look of iOS 7 and it has the default background as transparent.